# Using inputs as parameters in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Want to use inputs to be passed in range of another vector to extract corresponding value

Say for example see the Verilog code below.

But the problem is: I cant pass a variable(input) into the range of another  variable. But this has to be done like that.
Is there any other was to execute code with similar functionality? Actually my question pertains to the syntax correction of this code, and options available to execute similar functionality.

```
module foo(input1, input2, output1)
input [3:0] input1;
input [3:0] input2;
output reg [3:0] output1;
always@(*) begin
output1 <= input2[3:3-input1[1:0]];
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Can input1 be a verilog `paramter`? In other words, is it a known constant at instantiation of 'foo'?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take a slice out of the vector you have to work around the unequal size on the RHS and LHS. This is such a solution:

```
always @( * )  
case (input1)
2'b00 : output1 = input2[3];
2'b01 : output1 = input2[3:2];
2'b10 : output1 = input2[3:1]; 
2'b11 : output1 = input2[3:0]; 
endcase
```

I find that somewhat sloppy. The following is the same but the vectors are equal size on the RHS and LHS:

```
always @( * )  
case (input1)
2'b00 : output1 = {3'b000,input2[3]  };
2'b01 : output1 = { 2'b00,input2[3:2]};
2'b10 : output1 = {  1'b0,input2[3:1]};
2'b11 : output1 =         input2[3:0];
endcase
```

---

You suddenly mention an 8-bit input. I assume you mean that input2 is 8 bits wide. But that requires only a maximum length of input1 of 3 bits. So the solution above would be a twice as big but still feasible.

Just for your sake here is a version for a 8 bit index which requires 256 bit vectors. :-) It is a bit more difficult to understand but also works for your specific case where you always need only the MS X bits.

```
module foo( 
   input  [  7:0] input1,
   input  [255:0] input2,
   output [255:0] output1
);
wire [7:0] shift_right = 255-input;

   assign output1 = input2 >> shift_right ;

endmodule
```

Comment: would not it be possible to write it as: output1 = {(3-input1){1'b0}, input2[3-:input1+1'b1]}? Explanation: one can "repeat" a part by n_repetitions{part_to_repeat} and "dynamic" slicing can be done using offset and width with bus[offset-:width]. But be aware that the amount of required ressources increases quickly as many muxes are required.

Comment: This method will yield a very long code, as the intended input has 8 bits.

Comment: @ChristianB no, it will not b possible for the same reason: you need compile-time constants for 'repeat' and for 'indexing'.

Comment: ah you are right. The offset is allowed to be a variable but not the width. So one has to do a little workaround: wire [7:0] bus = {4'b0, input2};    always@(*) begin output1 <= bus[input1-:3]; end

Comment: @ChristianB. yes, bit it will not work in your case. Your scheme requires variable width. Therefore Oldfart's solution is the best one, unless 'input1' can be a real verilog parameter.

Comment: Sorry I dont get your comment. The later posted solution are synthesised just fine with my toolsset. The width is fixed (always equal to 3 in this case but can be chosen arbitrary). Same for the inputs. Basically it is a combined shift + slice/select subbus.

Comment: P.S. bascially bus[input1-:3]; should be similiar to (bus >> input1)[3:0].

Comment: @oldfart Thanks. I got an idea from your answer. I divided the input into 2 four bits. Put first four in case statement and next four in individual case statements. That somehow solved the problem(as not every of 16 cases was required in individual cases). But its ugly man, wanted to write a beautiful slim smart piece of code. But, such is life :)